# Spring 3 with Hibernate 3 Annotations - Session Factory Configuration

Tags: java, hibernate, spring

I am having very little luck configuring my spring config file for Hibernate Annotations. I have been looking at other posts and I'm not sure what I am missing. I shouldn't need to define a config file since I am using HibernateProperties in my session factory correct? I`m getting the following error:

## Error Message

### Error creating bean with name 'HibernateSessionFactory'

Could not instantiate bean class [org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.annotation.AnnotationSessionFactoryBean]: Constructor threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org.hibernate.cfg.AnnotationConfiguration

at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:965)

## Spring Configuration

```
<!--     Defines the hibernate session factory to be used by the hibernate support dao classes -->
<bean id="HibernateSessionFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.annotation.AnnotationSessionFactoryBean" >
    <property name="dataSource" ref="webDataSrc" />
    <property name="annotatedClasses"> 
            <list> 
                    <value>ca.test.Foo</value> 
            </list> 
    </property>

    <property name="hibernateProperties">
        <props>
            <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">true</prop>
            <prop key="debug">true</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.OracleDialect</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.cglib.use_reflection_optimizer">false</prop>
        </props>
    </property>
</bean>
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is `Hibernate Annotations` jar on your classpath?

Comment: No I have hibernate-3.2.6.ga.jar . I thought you didn't need the hibernate annotations jar anymore in version 3? Isn't it all bundled in 1 jar now?

Comment: http://www.findjar.com/jar/org/hibernate/hibernate/3.2.6.ga/hibernate-3.2.6.ga.jar.html?all=true

Comment: I can't find the `org.hibernate.cfg.AnnotationConfiguration` class there, so the answer is no. Maybe in the newer versions it is there.

Comment: Ya that was the issue. I like hibernate but fetching all its jars can be quite the pain. Thanks.